# According to Aquinas, does "love" towards something always bring "desire" towards that something?

Tags: love, thomas-aquinas, emotions

According to Thomas Aquinas, does "love" towards something ***always*** bring "desire" towards that something?

Comment: When you say "love," do you mean the Latin word *amor* or *caritas* (since Aquinas wrote [primarily] in Latin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

St. Thomas Aquinas defines love (*amor*) as something that "belongs to the appetitive [spec., [concupiscible](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS026.html#FSQ26A1THEP1)] power which is a [passive faculty](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS026.html#FSQ26A2THEP1)" ([*Summa Theologica* I-II q. 27 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS027.html#FSQ27A1THEP1) c.).

"Love (*amor*) is something pertaining to the appetite". ([*ibid.* I-II q. 26 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS026.html#FSQ26A1THEP1) c.)
"Passion is the effect of the agent on the patient." ([*ibid.* I-II q. 26 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS026.html#FSQ26A2THEP1) c.)

A sensitive appetite (i.e., an appetite pertaining to the senses) can be concupiscible or irascible. St. Thomas says ([*ibid.* I q. 81 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP081.html#FPQ81A2THEP1) c.) that the concupiscible appetitite is that

> through which the soul is simply inclined to seek what is suitable, according to the senses, and to fly from what is hurtful

The irascible is that

> whereby an animal resists these attacks that hinder what is suitable, and inflict harm

When you say "desire," it seems you mean what St. Thomas calls desire/cupidity or *desiderium*/*cupiditas* (cf. [*ibid.* I-II q. 40 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS040.html#FSQ40A1THEP1)).

Hope might be the irascible analogue of "love" that you're looking for (cf. [the aforementioned article](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS040.html#FSQ40A1THEP1)).